# How to Install Fedora/Pidora and Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu, fedora

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+ and a Windows Laptop, through which I have downloaded Pidora and made a bootable SD Card with Etcher Software. 
When I try to boot my Pi using this SD card it is not doing anything at all. What may I have done wrong here in this process?
The same problem also happens when using Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: "What may I have done wrong here" - you mean apart from not saying what you did?

Comment: Any lights? Did you have the verify option on Etcher?

Comment: Fedora Wiki states version 28+ and Ethernet connection is required for a 3B+ and by default  only uses HDMI - console output needs enabling.  Where did the name pidora come from???

Answer (score 0):

You do not tell much what you have done to flash the SD Card except that you used Etcher on a MS Windows PC. Yes, Etcher is the preferred software for flashing. For testing I suggest first to try the official supported operating system [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). It is known that it works. If it is also not booting then you are doing something wrong with Etcher and flashing or your the RPi 3B+ is broken. If it boots then the other images does not support the RPi 3B+.